# Interpolation binding does not work for Inline templates in AngularJS ui.bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, templates, data-binding, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using inline templates for a $modal in ui.bootstrap for AngularJS. The template has data bindings. The "ng-bind" form of binding works while the interpolation "{{ }}" does not. Also, data for "ng-repeat" is unavailable (which is the main problem)

I tried using non-inline template with templateUrl (involving a GET request) and interpolation seems to work then. The problem is that this template is quite Ruby-heavy with "form_tag"s and View helpers etc, hence I do not wish to extract it out into an external template.

Here's a Plunker demonstrating the problem http://goo.gl/heOD2m

Can anybody help me get the "ng-repeat" working, please? And possibly explain why this is happening.

Versions:
AgnularJS - v1.3.8
ui.bootstrap - v0.12.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer on Github: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3215#issue

In short, The modal HTML needs to be an "ng-template".

Here's the fixed plunker: 
http://goo.gl/po843F